# Performance prolem with this SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlperformance

I have built a SQL statement which delivers the right results, but the performance is a real problem. Any suggestions how to improve it would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    c~GROUP, c~CONTI, c~REGION, c~AREA, c~CNTRY,
    a~COMPANY, b~MATTYPE, a~CALMONTH, a~LOC_CURRCY, a~BASE_UOM,
    SUM(ZVALSTCKV) AS amount,
    SUM(ZVALSTCKQ) AS quantity
INTO 
    TABLE @data_raw1
FROM 
    AD3IM AS a
INNER JOIN 
    PMATERIAL AS b ON a~MATERIAL = b~MATERIAL
INNER JOIN 
    PCOMPANY AS c ON a~COMPANY = c~COMPANY
WHERE
    a~COMPANY IN @rangettable_COMPANY AND
    CALMONTH IN @rangetable_CALMONTH  AND
    (b~MATTYPE = @constant_O OR b~MATTYPE = @constant_T) AND
    b~OBJVERS = 'A' AND
    c~OBJVERS = 'A'
GROUP BY 
    a~COMPANY, b~MATTYPE, a~CALMONTH, a~LOC_CURRCY, a~BASE_UOM,
    c~GROUP, c~CONTI, c~REGION, c~AREA, c~CNTRY
```

AD3IM has about 2.8million records and as primary key:

```
COMPANY
SITECD
MATTYPE
CMATERIAL
CALMONTH
LOC_CURRCY
BASE_UOM
```

and there are no further indexes.

PMATERIAL is about 254.000 records and as primary key:

```
CMATERIAL
OBJVERS
```

and there are no further indexes.

PCOMPANY is about 14.000 records and as primary key:

```
COMPANY
OBJVERS
```

and there are no further indexes.

As I am a beginner in SQL I appreciate any assistance you may offer. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of sql platform is that?

Comment: Tag the database you are in. Then you gona need to provide more info, to start with what are `@rangettable_COMPANY` and `@rangetable_CALMONTH` are those tables, arrays, subselects? Then you gona need to provide also the execution plan for your query. Try to run it with fixed parameters to get the execution plan. And out of curiosity, what is this notation `c~GROUP` shouldn't it be `.` as of `c.GROUP`?

Comment: which  DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Running the query with `explain` in front will give you information about how the query is executing and what indexes its using. I'm going to guess something large in that `group by` is not indexed.

Comment: What is `a~MATERIAL` supposed to be?